# Cant able to detect which position is clicked in recycler view

Tags: android

I am creating a contact list app using SQL. So I want a `OnItemClickListener` to detect which item is being clicked and pass it to another activity.

My work is at: 
https://github.com/divyank00/ContactList

The error always is `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Please post your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are putting the position as an Integer Extra in your `MainAcitivity`, but you are trying to fetch it as a String in `contact_details.java` which isn't possible. To solve this:

Go to your `contact_details.java` class, move to **Line 59**:

```
//String position=intent.getStringExtra("pos");
//int pos=Integer.parseInt(position);
```

Replace these lines with this:

```
int pos = intent.getIntExtra("pos", 0);
```

Comment: Thank You sir. It worked. Can u explain me what was wrong in my code in detail? Means i catched the position in string and then converted it to int. Means i cant catch an int datatype in string??

Comment: And why did this crash my app.                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: `putExtra()` function is overloaded, which means there is different version of this function for each data type. you passed an integer so it called the integer function, if you convert your integer to string before passing it, you can retrieve it as string

Comment: Because it tried to use `position` but it was null. It was null because intent was searching for a **string with name "_pos_" ** and it didn't find it because it was stored as integer instead